# How are rest_framework.serializers and rest_framework.renderers related?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently following the tutorial : https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/profiles, where the serializer and Renderer are used.

Serializer : when a user submits information(such as creating an instance) through the API, the serializer,validates it and converts it into something Django can slot into a model instance.Similarly, deserializer converts python data-types into models or querysets(complex data-types)

Renderer classes: allow you to return responses with various media types.When a view is entered REST framework will perform content negotiation on the incoming request, and determine the most appropriate renderer to satisfy the request

I am not able to draw a distinction between the two.Request anyone to clearly outline the distinction between the two if possible with an example.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serializer is concerned with taking the original item - in most cases, the model instance - and converting it into Python primitives: strings, ints etc, contained in a single dictionary.

The renderer is concerned with how that is presented to the user; usually, converting that dictionary to JSON.

Comment: to put it in layman's terms, the data received by the user from the database is presented by the combination of two processes i.e 1) Serializer 2) Renderer . Thanks a lot for the help.